# I have tried installing ROS1(melodic) and ROS2(Dashing diademata) on the same OS(Ubuntu 18.04). I am doubtful about the sourcing of the bash script

Tags: ros, ros2, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I am trying to run talker and listener nodes to cross-check if python and C++ APIs are working properly for the newly installed ros2, It's not detecting ROS2. What should I do?
When I was trying to source the bash script for ros2 I got this result.

```
$ source /opt/ros/dashing/setup.bash
ROS_DISTRO was set to 'melodic' before. Please make sure that the environment does not mix paths from different distributions.
```

Is there any particular set of cautions that I should keep in mind?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351894/i-have-tried-installing-ros1(melodic)-and-ros2(dashing-diademata)-on-the-same-os(ubuntu-18.04).-i-am-doubtful-about-the-sourcing-of-the-bash-script./) by [Rupali](https://answers.ros.org/users/54002/rupali/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there any particular set of cautions that I should keep in mind?

Yes: do not auto-`source` the Melodic `setup.bash`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rupali](https://answers.ros.org/users/54002/rupali/) on 2020-05-09**:
Thanks!
I just edited the ~/.bashrc to remove the auto sourcing line. Now everytime I run a terminal I will have to manually source, showing the terminal where additionally look for while running ros1/ros2.